# SoftLayer API which User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission value controls "Power on"

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

On the SoftLayer Customer Portal list of devices, `Virtual Server -> Acton`, I can see action options of `"Reboot, Power On/Off, Rename device, View Audit Logs"`.

The SoftLayer API `SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission/getAllObjects` gives a list of permissions.

Which `SoftLayer_User_Customer_CustomerPermission_Permission` value should I revoke from the user account if I want to revoke the user's right to do  `Reboot/Power on/Power Off` and still leave the user's right of `"Rename device"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove this permission Rebbot/Power on, off/:

```
{
"key": "H_2"
"keyName": "REMOTE_MANAGEMENT"
"name": "IPMI"
}
```

and you have to grant this permission to rename the device:

```
{
"key": "H_7"
"keyName": "HOSTNAME_EDIT"
"name": "Hostname"
}
```

Comment: Nelson thank you for the update.  Does this "REMOTE_MANAGEMENT" only control permission for virtual server and bare metal server's  "power on / power off/reboot" ?  Does it control permission for any  action for other  type of products such as network /storage ?  I only want to remove user permission for  virtual server and bare metal server's  "power on / power off/reboot"  but don't want to change user permission for other type of products/actions.

Comment: the permission is the same that you see in the portal "Reboot server and view IPMI system information
Provides this user the ability to see IPMI details regarding hardware and issue reboot commands through the portal." This is the unique permission to avoid power on / power off /reboot all devices where you can do those actions will be affected.